Is there a standard notation for complementary and supplementary angles?
I recently was trying to solve a complex geometric problem using trigonometry and it made me wonder - is there a standard out there for annotating supplementary and complementary angles? I want to be clear: I'm not asking how to solve any particular problem, I'm asking if there's a standard shorthand notation in solving problems like this.
Here's a simple example (a line intersecting a rectangle) to illustrate my question. I was at a part of the drawing that looked similar to shapes below. I didn't want to label my angles a, b, c, etc., as this was one small part of a larger drawing and it would start to get very confusing. Instead, I used a "prime" notation, like below. Here, the angle denoted by $c$ has a complimentary angle, $c'$ and a supplementary angle, $c"$. So, $c' = 90 - c$ and $c" = 180 - c$.
After I did it, I thought primes might not be the best choice, as typically a "double prime" relates directly back to the "single prime". Whereas, in this case, both relate back to the original but in different ways (yes, I know that $c" = c' + 90$ but that's beside the point, the relation to c is the important part). I think a shorthand similar to this (maybe a "dot" type notation?) would be helpful solving complex geometric problems but I never ran into any such notation in any classes and I couldn't find a standard. Does one exist?


For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

The answer is no : I have never seen a shorthand notation proposal for such operations.

If often see, and use, an apostrophe for complements as in $a,a’$. But have not seen anything systematic for supplements.

I've used $\text{co},\theta$ for the complement of $\theta$, nicely echoing and intertwining cosine/cotangent/cosecant functions as the complementary sine/tangent/secant functions: $\cos(\theta)=\sin(\text{co},\theta)$, etc. (Also, $\text{co co }\theta=\theta$.) I've never really had cause to denote the supplement, but I'd probably go with $\text{su},\theta$; and maybe $\text{rx},\theta$ for the reflex.
